Which scenic location was used for the ascent to Master Genkai's training grounds?
In the third episode of Netflix's 2023 live-action adaptation of Yu Yu Hakusho, there's a scene where Yusuke, Kuwabara, and Botan make their way to Master Genkai's place for training. The setting is beautiful, and I'm curious if anyone knows where it was filmed.
The location features old, towering trees, stone steps leading to what appears to be a shrine, moss-covered stones, and lush greenery all around. From the looks of it, this place seems like it might be a popular tourist spot in real life.
I've included some screenshots from the episode:



I also found these images of the location on Kotone Furukawa's Instagram (she plays Botan in the show):

Has anyone recognized this location or know where these scenes were shot?
